# How to trigger a new X-Editable to open from the success function of the present one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using the [Bootstrap X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) to let people do inline edits of their profile. One of the things that the user can edit, has an influence on another editable though. If editable A (a year) is set to the current year, the user is obliged to make a decision in editable B (a certain tax rate) as well.

So the editable options for the editable `year` are as follows:

```
$('#year').editable({
    pk: 1,
    success: function(response, newValue){
        if (newValue == 2014){
            $('#tax_rate').trigger('click');
        } else {
            $('#tax_rate').html(2);
        }
    }
});
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE  HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vuonj996/)**

This behaves fine except for the year 2014, in which it does indeed post the correct value to the back-end, and subsequently indeed clicks/opens `#tax_rate`, but somehow, the click prevents the new year from being displayed correctly in `#year`. If I refresh the page, the year displays correctly again, but it's just when I try to trigger the other editable, that it doesn't display the year correctly after saving it. Just try opening [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vuonj996/) and changing the year to 2014 to see what I mean.

So does anybody know how I can both update the new year in the DOM and also click/open the `tax_rate` editable? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advice you to async UI interact:

Like this:

```
$('#year').editable({
    pk: 1,
    success: function(response, newValue){
        if (newValue == 2014){
          setTimeout(function(){
             $('#tax_rate').trigger('click');
          }, 0); 
        } else {
            $('#tax_rate').html(2);
        }
    }
});
```

It should work correctly, I think

**Add**:
Also you can trigger `click` event `vanillaJS` framework using.
I think `$.trigger` cause the some UI update fault.
It's simple:

```
document.getElementById('tax_rate')
  .dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

Comment: Need you some additional information? I add another way to fix that.

Comment: Awesome, that works indeed! Although it is solved now, would you happen to know *why* X-Editable behaves like this?

Comment: It seems like a magic :) I think poor implementation here. Something like updating invisible element by hardcoded timeout.